# Sort array by frequency

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, count

I would like to count how many times is every string in array and sort them by number of times they exist in array

I have this code now

```
hlasy.sort();

var zaciatok = null;
var pocet = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < hlasy.length; i++) {
    if (hlasy[i] != zaciatok) {
        if (pocet > 0) {
            console.log(zaciatok + ' má ' + pocet + ' hlasov');
        }
        zaciatok = hlasy[i];
        pocet = 1;
    } else {
        pocet++;
    }
}
if (pocet > 0) {
    console.log(zaciatok + ' má ' + pocet + ' Hlasov');
}
```

it works, but it outputs strings from array sorted by alphabet and no by how many times they are in array.

for example, it outputs

```
apple - 1
banana - 5
cherry - 4
```

but I need this

```
banana - 5
cherry - 4
apple - 1
```

thanks in advance

Comment: the data would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

Two passes. First, compute the number of occurrences of each word:

```
counter = Object.create(null);
words.forEach(function(word) {
   counter[word] = (counter[word] || 0) + 1;
});
```

Then, sort the array by comparing two words' counts:

```
words.sort(function(x, y) {
   return counter[y] - counter[x];
});
```