# Sort array item on the basis of frequency they are present Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, frequency

```
Input: [2,1,9,1,2,5,1,6,1]

Output: [5,6,9,2,2,1,1,1,1]
```

Follow the above transformation.

If the frequency is the same ascending order is to be maintained i.e 5,6,9 has the same frequency which is 1 therefore they're added in ascending order and followed by 2 (frequency 2)and 1 (frequency 4).

Please help to how to achieve this using javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array by frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008637/sort-array-by-frequency)

Answer (score 3):

Create a frequency object for each number in an object accumulator using `array#reduce` and then sort your array based on this object, for number having the same frequency, sort them on their value.

```js
const arr = [2,1,9,1,2,5,1,6,1],
      frequency = arr.reduce((r,v) => {
        r[v] = (r[v] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
      }, {});
arr.sort((a,b) => frequency[a] - frequency[b] || a - b);
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the frequency of occurrences, using the ternary operator

```
function sortByFrequency(myArray){
    var arr = [];
    var frequency = {};
    var i=myArray.length-1;
    for (var i;i>-1;i--){
        var tmp = myArray[i];
        frequency[tmp]==null?frequency[tmp]=1:frequency[tmp]++;
    }
    for (var tmp in frequency){
        arr.push(tmp);
    }
    function FreqCompare(x,y){
        return frequency[y]-frequency[x];
    }
    return arr.sort(FreqCompare);
}
```